# Does Tomcat require JDK or JRE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

I've read many articles and posts related to Tomcat and the Java runtime. I am confused and need help. Can anybody clear my doubt regarding whether Tomcat requires JDK or JRE?

Comment: Newer versions of tomcat run just fine with a JRE, older versions (I think up to and includeing 4.x) required a JDK. That's probably the source of the confusion.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Tomcat's [RUNNING.txt](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) which you can find in the root of the bundle states that Apache Tomcat requires Java Standard Edition Runtime Environment (JRE) to run. Minimum version of JRE depends on the version of Tomcat: for Tomcat 6.0 it is Java 5, for Tomcat 7.0 - Java 6.

However you can also use JDK because, as you probably know, it includes JRE ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/index.html)). The only difference is in the configuration of environment variables. If you use JRE you should set JRE_HOME, if JDK - JAVA_HOME. Read [RUNNING.txt](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) for more details.

P.S. Web containers may require JDK in order to support JSP, because Java Compiler is required to compile Servlets which are generated from *.jsp files. Tomcat has Eclipse Java Compiler bundle so it can run on JRE and still support JSP.

Comment: Thanks for the response.But can you clarify me which one is most preferable.

Comment: @JDeveloper: since a server should never have software installed that's not strictly required, you should definitely prefer the JRE, unless you *need* the JDK for some reason.

Comment: I have not thought about it, to be honest. In a development environment I just install JDK and use it with everything. In a production environment I agree with @JoachimSauer

Answer (score 15):

The only notable difference using JDK over JRE is to enable debug mode when launching tomcat jvm.

in the RUNNING.txt we don't have clear distinction, the text deals with certain options, without telling which one :

> Using JAVA_HOME provides access to certain additional startup options
>   that are not allowed when JRE_HOME is used.

the information is inside catalina.sh script :

```
#   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#                   Required to run the with the "debug" argument.
```

Answer (score 1):

I did successfully installation of `Apache Tomcat 7.0.56` when I installed `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171` .

Additional note: After I did successfully installation of `Apache Tomcat 7.0.56` when I installed `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171` I have seen in Java Control Panel -> Desktop Settings:

```
Web Enabled : checked 
Platform : 1.8 
Product : 1.8.0_171 
Architecture : x86 Type : 
User Path : C:\Program files (86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\javaw.exe 
Runtime Parametars : (empty field)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running **TOMCAT 7.0.92.0** builted in **XAMPP v3.2.4** installed in `C:\XAMPP` in a **Windows 10**.

I had installed **JDK** `jdk-13.0.2` with the following environment variables set:

```
CATALINA_HOME = "C:\xampp\tomcat"
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\"
JRE_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\"
```

*Tried also without setting `JRE_HOME` and also pointing it at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\`

But it wouldn't work until I installed **JRE** `jre1.8.0_241` and set `JRE_HOME` to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241\"

Right now in XAMPP's Control Panel it shows the server at "`Attempting to start Tomcat app..`", and never shows it at running mode, but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Above java 9 (jdk 1.9) Oracle no longer intends for end-users to be installing a JRE or a JDK.

so above java 9 you'll only find jdk without jre.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).