# Why does Tomcat require JDK installed?

Tags: java, tomcat

To my knowledge, JRE is run time and JDK is for development of the Java code. But on the Tomcat server in production, there would be no development of the Java application.

So, my question is why can't we run Tomcat installing only the JRE and why is JDK installation necessary for running Tomcat?

Comment: Because Tomcat needs the Java compiler. A JSP page is compiled into a Servlet and the compiler is not part of the JRE - but as far as I know newer versions can happily run with a JRE as well

Comment: Because `jstack` only ships with the JDK... and you're gonna need it!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Tomcat does **not** require a JDK. It needs a JRE only. JSP compilation is done by the bundled Eclipse compiler.

Answer (score 22):

<s>Because some of the functionality provided by Tomcat is only available in the JDK.</s>

For example, `jsp` pages must be parsed and any `Java` code in them must be compiled on-the-fly. This is not a feature available inthe `JVM`.

---

**Edit**

@Michael-O is absolutely right! *Tomcat does **not** require a JDK*. See [What tomcat requires JDK or JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16726897/823393) for a fuller explanation.

But note the comment [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q20).

> Tomcat 4 requires the full JDK. Tomcat 5.5 onwards will work with a JRE or a JDK.

Comment: The Tomcat 4 comment gave me useful historical context.