# Which configuration file tells Tomcat about the location of installed JRE?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

From the existing threads ([What tomcat requires JDK or JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726897/what-tomcat-requires-jdk-or-jre) and [Why does Tomcat require JDK installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988107/why-does-tomcat-require-jdk-installed?noredirect=1&lq=1#)) I learned that Tomcat 5.5 onwards does not need an installed JDK to compile jsp files, because it uses its own bundled Eclipse Java Compiler. However, when tomcat runs the java byte code, it does require JRE. But during installation of Tomcat, we only need to specify the location of JVM. To compile and run Java code, we only need to add bin folder under the JDK folder into the path environment. But JDK 9 does not include a JRE folder any more. Instead there is an independent JRE folder outside JDK folder. How does Tomcat still catches JRE when running compiled jsp code? Which configuration file in Tomcat captures this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> But during installation of Tomcat, we only need to specify the location of JVM

Specifying the location of the JVM implicitly specifies the location of the JRE, since the JVM is locate inside the JRE directory structure.

> To compile and run Java code, we only need to add bin folder under the JDK folder into the path environment.

Adding the JDK `bin` folder to the PATH, means that you can run the `java` and `javac` commands. The location of the command file implicitly specifies the location of the JDK, and hence the JVM, to use. There are no configuration files.

In Windows 64-bit Java 5 to Java 8, the JVM is located in `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`.

In Windows 64-bit Java 9, the JVM is located in `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\server\jvm.dll`.

> But JDK 9 does not include a JRE folder any more. Instead there is an independent JRE folder outside JDK folder.

The JDK installation programs for all Java versions will create both a JDK folder and a JRE folder, unless you tell it not to create the separate JRE folder. Java 9 is no different that older Java versions in that regard.

> How does Tomcat still catches JRE when running compiled jsp code?

Tomcat is itself written in Java, so Tomcat doesn't locate Java. It is Java that runs Tomcat.

Comment: I am asking how does Tomcat know where JRE is located in order to run .class file compiled from .jsp. I am not asking how Java runs .class (I know javac and java are involved in the case of Java). We only tell Tomcat where JVM is located, i.e., %JAVA_HOME%\bin\server\jvm.dll. But In Java 9, JRE is not inside, but outside the JDK folder (i.e., outside %JAVA_HOME%). Also, please note that for JDK 9, the JDK folder does not include a JRE folder. For exmaple, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1 and C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1, the former does not include the latter.

Comment: Did you read my answer at all? The JVM and all the Java Runtime Library are all part of the Java 9 JDK. Sure, they are not located in an `JRE` subfolder, but everything that is in a JRE is also in the JDK. --- But to you first point, please read last part of answer again: Tomcat does not locate Java. **Tomcat is run by Java**, and Java already knows where itself is. The Java code of Tomcat simply calls the JSP compiled Java classes using reflection. Tomcat doesn't have to locate Java to do that, because **Java is already running it all**.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch the your explanation entirely at the beginning. I am trying to understand it better. So the process is like this: 1) .jsp is converted to .java, 2) .java is compiled to .class, both steps are within Tomcat, and 3) .class is run by JVM, which is beyond the scope of Tomcat, but is fully done in Java. Is this what you mean? Thanks.